# Pair items from array in unique groups

Tags: ruby, combinatorics

I have an array of numbers (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`). These numbers represent players. I would like these players to each "play" each other exactly once.

I need to create "Rounds" for these games. These rounds will include a even number of matches, and each player can only play in a round, at most, once. If there's an odd number of matches, than a final round with irregular number of matches is okay.

The end result being an array of "Round" arrays. These round arrays will contain the matches between players. The end result being something like below, but complete:

`[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]],[[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,8],[9,1],[10,2]]]`

I've found `Array#combination` for getting the matches created, but I can't seem to get the rounds to build properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a round robin tournament. Wikipedia gives the following [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm)

```
Round 1. (1 plays 14, 2 plays 13, ... )
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 14 13 12 11 10 9  8
```

then fix one competitor (number one in this example) and rotate the others clockwise one position:

```
Round 2. (1 plays 13, 14 plays 12, ... )
 1  14 2  3  4  5  6
 13 12 11 10 9  8  7
```

And keep rotating:

```
Round 3. (1 plays 12, 13 plays 11, ... )
 1  13 14 2  3  4  5
 12 11 10 9  8  7  6
```

An odd number of players is handled by one player per round having no game (often implemented by adding a dummy player).